# Continuous time Markov Chain help

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose that the price of company stock is increasing if the latest news are positive. News article arrive with a Poisson distribution of intensity 2 per day. Furthermore , good news arrive with probability of 2/3.

Find the Q matrix and the long term proportion of time that the price of a stocks is increasing.

---

This is a practice HW. I dont know how solve continuous time markov chain. What we have seen in class is the Poisson process , the M/M/1 and the Birth and death model. I'm not sure which model to apply.

Comment: You first determine the number of states (here the number of states is finite and small).  Then you determine the transition rates between states. This is simpler than an M/M/1 queue and is one of the simplest possible birth-death chains.

Comment: there's only 2 state , so Q=  { { -2/3 , 2/3 } ,  {1/3 ,-1/3 } }

Comment: So, what is the physical meaning of your states, and how did you get $q_{12} = 2/3$?  [In other words, how does one verify your work?]

Comment: its the probability of good news $q_{12}=2/3$

Comment: So why should it be in the upper right corner?

Comment: because it's increasing $j=i+1$

Comment: Not clear.  You haven't specified your states yet, so, it is impossible to know where the entries should be.

Comment: state 1 = good news , state 2 = bad news ?

Comment: Okay, so, where do you use the fact that news arrives like a Poisson process of rate 2 per day?  Would your $Q$ matrix change if it was rate 19 per day?

Comment: so $q12=2$ which is the rate of the poisson  or $q12=2/3$ which is the probability of a good news...

Comment: it should be $q12=2$ because Q is an intensity matrix

Comment: This is an issue between discrete time chains (where we use probabilities that are less than 1) and continuous time (where we use rates that can be more than 1).  In your case, news is Poisson of rate 2, but it is _independently split_ in the sense that every news item is independently good with probability $2/3$ and bad otherwise.  Do you know any results about splitting Poisson processes? If we are in state 2 (bad news) and another bad news arrives, we stay where we are.  So the transition rate from bad to good should be _less_ than 2.

Comment: sorry I'm lost now...

Comment: Where did you get lost? [If you look at it another way, you know your $Q$ matrix should describe the system, and hence should include the $2$ parameter, the $2/3$ parameter, and the $1/3$ parameter, if you ignore any of these you know you are incorrect.]

Comment: so what is the q matrix..?

Comment: $q21=2/3$ and $q12=4/3$ and the sum of good news and bad new is $q21+q21=2$

Comment: The above $q_{21}$ and $q_{12}$ values might be mixed up, depending on the definitions of states, for 2=bad, 1=good I think it should be the reverse of your above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer summarizes our discussion.  We have a continuous time Markov chain with 2 states 
\begin{align}
\mbox{state 1} &= \mbox{good news} \\
\mbox{state 2} &= \mbox{bad news} 
\end{align} 
The $2 \times 2$ transition rate matrix $Q$ has important parts given by:

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}* & q_{12} \\ q_{21} & * \end{bmatrix}$$
where $q_{ij}$ is the transition rate associated with going from $i$ to $j$: 
\begin{align}
q_{12} &= \mbox{rate of getting bad news, given we are in state 1} \\
q_{21} &= \mbox{rate of of getting good news, given we are in state 2} 
\end{align}
Suppose we are in the bad state (state 2).  Then transition rates are described by the second row of $Q$ and: 
$$ \underbrace{\mbox{rate of good news}}_{q_{21}} + \mbox{rate of bad news} = 2 \: (\mbox{per day}) $$
We can derive the value of $q_{21}$ by viewing this as the i.i.d. split of a Poisson process of rate $2$, and using results of splitting Poisson processes.

Once we have the $Q$ matrix, we can get the steady state values for each state by solving the corresponding birth-death chain.  You will find that the steady state will only depend on the splitting probability and not on the rate $\lambda$ of the Poisson process. On the other hand, the $Q$ matrix will be proportional to $\lambda$ (in this case, $\lambda= 2$ per day).